# Azure Cosmos DB- Trigger Change Feed only for specific values using Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We want to trigger Azure Function on Cosmos DB change feed, but only when there is a specific value inserted into cosmos DB.

For example. Here is the json sample which we are storing into cosmos DB.

```
{
    "EventGuid": "3ecab093-564e-4642-9e5c-097ab89a03c9",
    "NotificationType": 11,
    "NotificationTypeDesc": "CardGroupChanged",
    "UserUUId": "06db4897-e63a-4be7-bd24-c5b59749a5b3",
    "GroupName": null,
    "Payer": "CZ00001927",
    "Account": "CZ00001927",
    "Status": 3,
    "StatusDesc": "Sent",
    "Created": "2020-04-24T15:46:43.5109248Z",
    "Updated": null,
    "SubscriptionId": "02071132-1927-4be7-bd24-c5b59749a5b3",
    "SubscriptionAction": 2,
    "SubscriptionActionDesc": "Email",
    "DistributionType": 1,
    "DistributionTypeDesc": "Single",
    "ReadBy": null,
    "PayerName": "Gabbar Singh Pvt Ltd",
    "AccountName": "Samba Roadways"
}
```

Can i trigger cosmos db change feed using Azure Functions only when there is `SubscriptionAction` having value 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no. The logic and compute necessary for determine when to do something must be within the Azure Function itself. There is no mechanism for determining when to fire Change Feed within Cosmos DB itself.

Comment: Thanks! @Mark, Can we trigger change feed azure function only for insertion not on updation?

Comment: No. Change Feed fires each time. We are working on including the operation type in change feed to say what the operation is but not whether it fires at all. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @MarkBrown, do you have news on operationType information on the change feed?

Comment: Still has not shipped yet. Sorry. On our roadmap for this Spring.